# asp.net mvc spa durandaljs date format not working with Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, durandal, hottowel

I'm exploring durandaljs for asp.net mvc SPA. I'm using APS.net MVC4, Durandaljs, Knockoutjs, breeze, moment and other libs found under hottowel SPA sample.

I have a client view which is bound with DOB, DateTime.

```
    <td colspan="2">
                    <span id="dob" data-bind="text: DOB"></span>
            </td>
```

and my ViewModel contains code

```
    vm.studentProfile().DOB(moment(vm.studentProfile().DOB()).format('L'));
        logger.log(vm.studentProfile().DOB(), null, system.getModuleId(vm), false);
```

Above code actually comes from querySucceeded. i.e

```
    return manager
        .executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);
```

This supposed to be working as I've achieved this already for some other fields but in case of DateTime KnockoutOut doesn't update GUI whereas I can see the UPDATED format date in console log. Can somebody tell me what am I missing here. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may lie with the fact that DOB is a `MomentJs` date, not a JavaScript `Date` or string. You most likely need to add a custom binding handler for displaying these dates, such as for example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.moment = {
            update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                var formattedValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value).format('LLLL');
                $(element).text(formattedValue);
            }
};
```

Now, instead of using the "text" binding handler, use the "moment" binding handler like this:

```
<span id="dob" data-bind="moment: DOB"></span>
```

Edit: added an example of adding custom plugins using AMD modules with RequireJS:

```
require(['jquery', 'json2', 'sammy', 'amplify', 'bootstrap', 'moment', 'toastr', 'showdown', 'markdowneditor', 'spin'], 
        function($){

        // Require that plugins be loaded, after the prerequisite libraries
        //       We load the plugins here and now so that we don't have to 
        //       name them specifically in the modules that use them because
        //       we don't want those modules to know that they use plugins.
        requirejs([
                'jquery.ui',                // jquery plugin
                'jquery.mockjson',          // jquery plugin
                'jquery.tmpl',          // jquery plugin
            ], 
            function () { 
                require(['ko'],
                    function(ko) {
                        // ensure KO is in the global namespace ('this') 
                        if (!this.ko) {
                            this.ko = ko;
                        };

                        requirejs([
                                'libs/knockout.binding.handlers',       // Knockout custom binding handlers
                                'libs/knockout.extenders',       // Knockout custom binding handlers
                                'libs/bootstrap.extenders',       // Knockout custom binding handlers
                            ],
                            // Plugins generally don't return module objects
                            // so there would be point in passing parameters to the function
                            function () { 
                                require(['app'], function(App) {
                                    App.initialize(); 
                                });
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: i tried this already but it doesn't work from ViewModel.. I've just found that I'd need to place it in global js file... should work but I already got it working with JQuery and viewAttached. Now I'm just trying to work out my calendar control.. which is not behaving as it should be within durandal..

Comment: can you tell me where I can put this code... and how to use it i'm using require... i put in global js but that doesn't go well. 

I mean the amd modules.. i'm just a beginner

Comment: If you are using requireJs, you have to add the binding handler after KnockoutJS has been loaded. Alternatively, if you just want to check if it works first before doing dozens of changes, you may just modify KnockoutJs's script and include this new binding handler in it. Don't worry about amd modules, it is hard even when you are not a beginner :-)

Comment: @afr0 I've added an example I've used for one of my pet projects. There are certainly some modules you don't have, but you get the idea. The key is to add the KnockoutJS custom bindings after it has been loaded.

Comment: this code would take life time for me to test actually... i hate js date pickerz and this is the reason i'd stick to my working workaround for the time being :D. I know i can't escape it though but will try it

Answer (score 0):

What about just making a ko.Computed like the following

```
vm.studentProfileFormatted = ko.computed({
  read: function () {
    return moment(vm.studentProfile().DOB()).calendar();
  },
  write: function (value) {
    var time = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").toJSON();
      vm.studentProfile(time);
  },
  owner: vm
});
```

And then calling studentProfileFormatted in your view.